# Google Debug API Clarification

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I hope that I can be clear; I know there are a lot of threads on the Google Map API, but I have exhausted my brain trying to fix my problem with the maps. Please tell me what I have wrong here.

I understand there are two Google Map API keys. 
1)  API key, for a market published app. Maps will appear once the app is published.
2)  Debug API key, only works on emulator or side loaded to the phone for testing.

My partner and I are working on an app together from different PC’s. We each have our own debug api key.

1)  He sends his app folder from his .android folder
2)  I drop the files into folder in my .android folder
3)  I import the project into eclipse
4)  Replace his API key with mine.
5)  Run application

He gets maps displaying on his application, but I do not. I get the gray grid.

Do I need to build a new APK of the app before the maps will appear? Does this new APK have to be created exactly like he did his?

Does the path to my APK need to be in the same folder as my keytool.debug?

How does the fingerprint relate to the APK?

Please clarify, we are stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps API key is linked to the keystore which was used to register.  You will need the debug.keystore that was used to register for the API key.  [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/share-a-debug-maps-key) are some quick instructions I found on how to do this.

Sharing one keystore is much easier than changing the reference to a new maps API key every time you make a revision.  I'm not sure why your method isn't working though.

Comment: So, He can just drop his APK and Keystore into a single folder, give it to me, then we could be using the same debug apikey? Is that right? Sounds too easy.